# vhdl clock input to output as a finite state machine

Tags: vhdl

[image]
I have to generate the vhdl code for the signal generator above as a finite state machine. What I cant manage to implement is this. How to generate
the clock values to output. To be more specific, I want for half period
output 0 and the other half 1, when the state machine is in state clock. My implementation, as you can see on the
code below, is output <= clock but this obviously does not work. I made a finite machine with 4 states (s1, s2, s3, s4)

My testbench and my vhdl code are these:

testbench

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity signal_generator_tb is
end entity;

architecture signal_generator_tb_arch of signal_generator_tb is
  signal clock_tb, reset_tb: std_logic;
  signal output_tb: std_logic;

  component signal_generator
    port(clock, reset: in std_logic;
       output: out std_logic);
  end component;

  begin
    dut : signal_generator port map(clock_tb, reset_tb, output_tb);

    stim_reset : process
      begin
        reset_tb <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
        reset_tb <= '1'; wait;
    end process;

    stim_clock : process
      begin
        clock_tb <= '1'; wait for 10 ns;
        clock_tb <= '0'; wait for 10 ns;
      end process;

end architecture;
```

and my vhdl code is that:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity signal_generator is
  port (clock, reset: in std_logic;
       output: out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture signal_generator_arch of signal_generator is
  type state_type is (s0, s1, s2, s3); --This is the states of the 
finite state machine and we can create signlas with this type
  signal current_state, next_state: state_type; --We can only assign 
w_open and w_closed because there are type of state_type

  begin
    STATE_MEMORY : process(clock, reset)
      begin
        if(reset = '0') then
          current_state <= s0;
        elsif(falling_edge(clock)) then
          current_state <= next_state;
        end if;
      end process;

    NEXT_STATE_LOGIC : process(current_state)
      begin
        case(current_state) is
          when s0 => next_state <= s1;
          when s1 => next_state <= s2;
          when s2 => next_state <= s3;
          when s3 => next_state <= s0;
          when others => next_state <= s0;
        end case;
      end process;

    OUTPUT_LOGIC : process(current_state)
      begin
        case(current_state) is
          when s0 => output <= '1';
          when s1 => if(rising_edge(clock)) then
                  output <= '1';
                else
                  output <= '0';
                end if;
          when s2 => output <= '1';
          when s3 => output <= '0';
          when others => output <= '0';
        end case;
      end process;
end architecture;
```

wave form
[image]

Comment: For this to work in an FPGA, you're going to need the clock that generates the output to be running at 2x `clock` speed. no FPGA technologies will allow registers to work on both clock edges (other than some FPGAs with DDR register on the pins)

Comment: Currently just want to test it with modelsim and see that it works correctly. Only the clock output (s2 state) works incorrectly and I cant manage to figure out how to correct it

Comment: The answer below will work. But will need to be re-designed completely if you want to use it on actual hardware.

Comment: @Tricky I wouldn't say that. It strongly depends on the target hardware, if any (ASIC or FPGA), on the availability of clock buffers and the constraints on their use, the use that is made of the gated clock... All this is not specified in the OP and cannot be guessed. Depending on the use case it could be directly usable, usable with ad hoc synthesis constraints or not directly usable.

Comment: @Tricky  Anyway, if what you have in mind is the need for a twice faster clock, because clock gating would be forbidden, _re-designed completely_ is probably a bit exaggerated. What would be needed is just adding one LSB to the counter and use it instead of `clock` in the concurrent signal assignment. Not a big deal.

Comment: @Tricky Another option would be to have two state registers, one sampled on rising edges and the other on falling edges. The output would then be derived from the two states and there would be no need for a faster clock. And there, yes, it would be a significant change.

Answer (score 0):

Your state machine does not work because of your `OUTPUT_LOGIC` process. It should also be sensitive to `clock` and when in state `s1` it should output `clock` itself:

```vhdl
OUTPUT_LOGIC : process(current_state, clock)
      begin
        case(current_state) is
          when s0 => output <= '1';
          when s1 => output <= clock;
          when s2 => output <= '1';
          when s3 => output <= '0';
          when others => output <= '0';
        end case;
      end process;
```

Note that you could simplify all this by simply passing your clock through a AND gate (to force it to 0) and a OR gate (to force it to 1) and output the result. A two bits counter that you would initialize to `"11"` and decrement would provide the current state, encoded in a very convenient way to force the output to 0 and 1:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity signal_generator is
  port(clock, reset: in std_ulogic;
       output: out std_ulogic);
end entity signal_generator;

architecture arc of signal_generator is
  signal cnt: std_ulogic_vector(1 downto 0); -- the state 
begin

  process(clock, reset)
  begin
    if reset = '0' then
      cnt <= "11";
    elsif falling_edge(clock) then
      cnt <= cnt - 1;
    end if;
  end process;

  output <= (clock and cnt(1)) or cnt(0);

end architecture arc;
```

Note: always prefer `std_ulogic` (unresolved) to `std_logic` (resolved) when you do not plan to have multiple drive situations on a signal. This way, if you accidentally create a multiple drive situation you will get a meaningful error message instead of spending hours trying to understand where all these `X` values in your waveforms come from.

Comment: Sorry for all those questions but I am very new to VHDL programming. How the state machine can be sensitve to clock?
elsif(falling_edge(clock)) then
     current_state <= next_state;
    elsif(rising_edge(clock)) then
     current_state <= next_state;
I  made this but does not work

Comment: Why do you want your state machine to change its current state on both edges of the clock? What do you mean with _does not work_? Did you simulate what I suggest?

Comment: I added the waveform of the simulation. When in s1 only outputs 0. I want the second half of the periof to be 1. What am I missing?

Comment: @christos.goulas Did you read my answer and did you try what I suggest instead of your non-working code?

Comment: Yes I changed the OUTPUT_LOGIC according to your answer and simulate and add the waveform.

Comment: You must have missed something. When in state `s1` the `output` shall be exactly like `clock`, while your waveforms show zero. If you really use the `OUTPUT_LOGIC` I suggest you cannot have these waveforms. Did you recompile **ALL** source files and re-simulate? Did you **COPY-PASTE EXACTLY** the code I show? Are you sure you simulate the **RIGHT** design?

Comment: And, by the way, please try to keep your question consistent. Do not update only parts of it. If you modify your source code and simulate, please update **both** the source code and the waveforms in your question. Else it will quickly become unusable by others, and it will very likely be down-voted and closed.

Comment: Thanks both for your patient and advices. I copy paste your soloution and works fine!